# Deleted all files in dir, except ones within a json file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a static assets server with 1 million+ images sitting in a folder, most of them I don't need anymore.

I have a list of the filenames I do still need in a .json file.

How in bash can I delete every file in that directory, except if the file name exists in the json list?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those filenames don't need quoting (no spaces and have no special characters):

```
$ cat keep.json 
["file1.png", "file2.png"]

find -not '(' $(php -r  'echo "-name " . implode(" -o -name ", json_decode(file_get_contents("keep.json")));') ')' -delete
```

Run the command from the folder whose contents you want to delete. If you run without `-delete`, a list of the matched files will be shown (instead of deleted).